# KeyPress (Enter) In Telerik ComboBox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

There found lack in Telerik compobox No keyPress event found so i use special function and there found 2 notes i cant solve it , i hope if any person can help me to solve this lack

1- when use this function i handle keypress event but arrows not working what can i put to make up and down arrows working

2- I want to send tap if keypress=13 how can i do this instead of focus on special control.

```
<script>
kendo.ui.ComboBox.fn._keydown = function (e) {
    var that = this,
    key = e.keyCode;
    that._last = key;



    clearTimeout(that._typing);

    if (key == kendo.keys.DOWN) {
       that._downArrow(); //this not working what can i put here to use down arrow
    }

    if (key == kendo.keys.UP) {
        that._upArrow(); //this not working what can i put here to use up arrow
    }

    if (key !== kendo.keys.TAB &&
     key !== kendo.keys.DOWN &&
     key !== kendo.keys.UP) {
        that._search();

    }

    // what can i put here to send Tap
};
```